# Find the nearest element in a sorted vector in R

Tags: r, algorithm, math, vector, floating-point

I want to find which value in a sorted vector is nearest to a given value. If there are two or more nearest values, `NA` is expected. For example,

> ```
> > vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> > find.nearest(vec, 2.51)
> [1] 3
> > find.nearest(vec, 2.5)
> [1] NA
> ```

This is my implementation:

```
find.nearest <- function(vec, x) {    # here `vec` is sorted
  nearest.idx <- which.min(abs(vec - x))
  nearest <- vec[nearest.idx]
  if ((x*2 - nearest) %in% vec ||
      duplicated(vec, fromLast=TRUE)[nearest.idx]) {
    return(NA)
  }
  return(nearest)
}
```

It works in most cases. However, floating point quirks are causing problems:

> ```
> > vec <- c(0.1, 0.3)
> > x <- 0.2
> > find.nearest(vec, x)
> [1] 0.3
> ```

Instead of `NA`, `0.3` is incorrectly returned, presumably because 0.2 x 2 - 0.3 is not exactly 0.1 in floating point arithmetic. How would you address this?

Comment: In order to answer this correctly, you need to characterize the data in some ways. Several answers have recommending “comparing with a tolerance.” But such as a comparison decreases false negatives (occasions where the comparison reports false because the computed values differ from the ideal mathematical values, for which the comparison would be true) at the expense of increasing false positives. Neither of the answers suggesting “comparing with a tolerance” address this.

Comment: Unless your numbers take on only discrete values, widely separated from each other, “comparing with a tolerance” will produce incorrect results when there are numbers that are closer to each other than the tolerance but are so close because their ideal mathematical values are in fact close, not because rounding errors put them so close. So, knowing whether this problem can be solved by “comparing with a tolerance” requires knowing more about the data you are working with.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My data are floating point numbers ranging from 0 to 100, and each of them have up to 17 significant digits. The vector typically contains dozens of numbers, so performance isn’t a great issue here.

Comment: If your numbers are not guaranteed to be separated by some amount greater than the unit of least precision at their scale (2\*\*-46 for numbers around 100), then comparing with a tolerance cannot work; it will falsely indicate numbers are close. It seems like you may be trying to treat numbers as decimal even though your software uses binary floating point. That creates issues that need to be understood before solutions can be crafted.

Comment: You write in the question “0.3 is incorrectly returned, presumably because 0.2 x 2 - 0.3 is not exactly 0.1 in floating point arithmetic.” It is not arithmetic that causes the issue at this point. It is the fact that, the results of converting .1, .2, and .3 to binary floating point are not equally spaced, due to what is possible in binary floating point. The information that .1 and .3 were equally close to .2 is gone, and it is impossible to restore it from the floating point values alone. Are you **sure** your numbers can have **any** values in your range with 17 decimal digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find.nearest <- function(vec, x, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) { 
 dist <- abs(vec - x)
 min <- min(dist)
 ind <- which(abs(dist - min) < tol)
 if (length(ind) == 1L) vec[ind] else as(NA, class(vec))
}

vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

find.nearest(vec, 2.51)
#[1] 3
find.nearest(vec, 2.5)
#[1] NA

vec <- c(0.1, 0.3)

find.nearest(vec, 0.2)
#[1] NA
```

You always need to use a tolerance when comparing floating point numbers. Obviously, this function is not vectorized.

PS: If your vector is huge it might make sense to make use of it being sorted for efficiency, but usually you don't need to bother. If this is really a concern, I'd suggest Rcpp anyway.

Comment: Neat! Performance is not a big problem. However, I don't understand what's the point of `as(NA, class(vec)` instead of `NA`. Also, why should we use `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` instead of `.Machine$double.eps`?

Comment: If I don't set a class, a logical `NA` value is returned. I prefer to have the class of the result only depend on the class of the input vector. The default tolerance was chosen to match the tolerance used by `all.equal`. You can of course use a different default.

Comment: Plus, do we really need `1L` instead of `1`? (sorry, I know I'm asking too many questions, but you know, I'm not skilled in R...)

Comment: No, you don't need to compare to an integer 1. R will coerce types automatically during comparison (see `help("==")`). However, since comparison is the main issue here, I wanted to make it obvious that we compare integer values there.

Comment: “Comparing with a tolerance” enables the code to find results where it is assumed the actual present values come from some ideal values but have some amount of rounding error, and we want to compute as if we had real values rather than the actual computed values. But it also enables false results where the ideal results would not satisfy the desired test but the tolerance allows them to slip by. This answer presents no caution about that and uses an arbitrary tolerance with no justification. Further, the tolerance is absolute, whereas floating-point representation is inherently relative.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand some part of your code (this part `(x*2 - nearest) %in% vec`). But, I think I fixed the part you are interested in. I guess you can add the checking for duplicated in the commented part of the code.

```
find.nearest <- function(vec, x) {    # here `vec` is sorted

  nearest_idx1 <- which.min(abs(vec - x - .Machine$double.eps))
  nearest_idx2 <- which.min(abs(vec - x + .Machine$double.eps))

  if (nearest_idx1 != nearest_idx2)
    return(NA)

  nearest <- vec[nearest_idx1]

  #check for anything else
  #  if ((x*2 - nearest) %in% vec ||

  if (duplicated(vec, fromLast=TRUE)[nearest_idx1]) {
    return(NA)
  }

  return(nearest)
}
```

Test

```
vec <- c(0.1, 0.3)
x <- 0.2
find.nearest(vec, x)
#[1] NA

find.nearest(vec, 0.1)
#[1] 0.1
find.nearest(vec, 0.4)
#[1] 0.3
find.nearest(vec, 0)
#[1] 0.1
```

Comment: “Comparing with a tolerance” enables the code to find results where it is assumed the actual present values come from some ideal values but have some amount of rounding error, and we want to compute as if we had real values rather than the actual computed values. But it also enables false results where the ideal results would not satisfy the desired test but the tolerance allows them to slip by. This answer presents no caution about that and uses an arbitrary tolerance with no justification. Further, the tolerance is absolute, whereas floating-point representation is inherently relative.

Comment: In addition, note that the tolerance is unreasonable. The “machine epsilon” is the increment from 1 to the next representable number. But the question shows sample values such as 2.51. At that scale, no numbers can differ by a value as small as the “machine epsilon” (the steps at 2.51 are twice as large as the steps at 1), and hence comparing with that tolerance is equivalent to comparing for exact equality.